# SQL*Plus ORA-00904 invalid identifier & ORA-00905 missing keyword (foreign key)

Tags: oracle, ddl, create-table, ora-00904, ora-00905

I've tried to debug this code to the best of my ability to eliminate the possibility of little mistakes being the reason these errors are occurring but I keep getting two different errors on three create table statements.

The CREATE TABLE SECTION statement gives an invalid identifier error on line 7 pointing to course#, here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION
(SECTION#   VARCHAR2(8) constraint pk_section# primary key,
TIME   CHAR(5),
MAXST   NUMBER(2),
ROOM   VARCHAR2(14),
constraint chk_maxst check(maxst<=35),
constraint fk_crs foreign key(course#)
REFERENCES course(course#),
constraint fk_pro foreign key(empid)
REFERENCES professor(empid));
```

The CREATE TABLE TAKES statement gives an invalid identifier error on line 4 pointing to section#, here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE TAKES
(GRADE   CHAR(5) constraint nn_grade not null,
constraint chk_grade check(grade IN ('A','B','C')),
constraint fk_sec foreign key(section#)
REFERENCES section (section#),
constraint fk_stu foreign key(sid)
REFERENCES student(sid));
```

Full Context:

```
drop table professor cascade constraints;
drop table course cascade constraints;
drop table student cascade constraints;
drop table section cascade constraints;
drop table takes cascade constraints;

CREATE TABLE PROFESSOR
(NAME  CHAR(15) constraint nn_name not null,
EMPID VARCHAR2(8) constraint pk_empid primary key,
PHONE NUMBER(10),
DATEHIRED DATE,
SALARY NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE COURSE
(NAME   CHAR(24) constraint nn_names not null,
COURSE# CHAR(10) constraint pk_course# primary key,
CREDIT  CHAR(6) constraint nn_credit not null,
COLLEGE CHAR(20),
HRS   NUMBER(1),
constraint chk_credit check(credit IN('U','G')),
constraint chk_college check(college IN ('Arts and Sciences','Education','Engineering','Business')),
constraint chk_course check((credit='U' AND hrs<=4) OR (credit = 'G' AND hrs=3)),
constraint unq_course unique(name, college));

CREATE TABLE STUDENT
(SID   VARCHAR2(7) constraint pk_sid primary key,
NAME    CHAR(14),
ADDRESS  CHAR(22),
BIRTHDATE DATE,
GRADELEVEL CHAR(2) constraint nn_glvl not null);

CREATE TABLE SECTION
(SECTION#   VARCHAR2(8) constraint pk_section# primary key,
TIME   CHAR(5),
MAXST   NUMBER(2),
ROOM   VARCHAR2(14),
constraint chk_maxst check(maxst<=35),
constraint fk_crs foreign key(course#)
REFERENCES course(course#),
constraint fk_pro foreign key(empid)
REFERENCES professor(empid));

CREATE TABLE TAKES
(GRADE   CHAR(5) constraint nn_grade not null,
constraint chk_grade check(grade IN ('A','B','C')),
constraint fk_sec foreign key(section#)
REFERENCES section (section#),
constraint fk_stu foreign key(sid)
REFERENCES student(sid));

Textbook references:
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eDdBShzgnSjISqxByJ7FKgbkLCEwXzpd][1]
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WhDsgQy2xSwjxVMqDzaGOcBh7zSokneT][2]
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=12N51OCEucRn_unagqHYsqufEGK3tKJH_][3]
```

Comment: Your colmun names do not have the crs_ prefix, why do you put this prefix in contraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow documentation that describes how you are supposed to do what you are doing? Because, it seems that you didn't pay much attention at classes, nor read documentation and tend to *make up* things, doing something that is either wrong or doesn't ever exist.

Consider deleting all that mess and starting over.

Here are some guidelines; try to fix those mistakes, come back if it still doesn't work.

In the **COURSE** table:

- don't use CHAR but VARCHAR2 data type
- you can't create constraints on non-existent columns (for example, a check constraint on CRS_CREDIT column, while you named the column as CREDIT)

In the **SECTION** table:

- don't use CHAR data type
- you can't use columns (in FOREIGN KEY constraints) that don't exist in the SECTION table (such as SEC_CRS_COURSE#), nor in the table you reference (such as CRS_COURSE# in the COURSE table)
- there are no ON UPDATE CASCADE nor ON DELETE RESTRICT in Oracle

The same goes for the **TAKES** table.

---

**[EDIT, after you *almost* made it work]**

Congratulations! You're now so close! SECTION and TAKES table need some adjustment (missing columns - have a look, I marked them with a comment) and then tables are successfully created.

Once again (as you won't listen): get rid of CHAR data type columns - use VARCHAR2 instead.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE PROFESSOR
  2  (
  3     NAME        CHAR (15) CONSTRAINT nn_name NOT NULL,
  4     EMPID       VARCHAR2 (8) CONSTRAINT pk_empid PRIMARY KEY,
  5     PHONE       NUMBER (10),
  6     DATEHIRED   DATE,
  7     SALARY      NUMBER
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE COURSE
  2  (
  3     NAME      CHAR (24) CONSTRAINT nn_names NOT NULL,
  4     COURSE#   CHAR (10) CONSTRAINT pk_course# PRIMARY KEY,
  5     CREDIT    CHAR (6) CONSTRAINT nn_credit NOT NULL,
  6     COLLEGE   CHAR (20),
  7     HRS       NUMBER (1),
  8     CONSTRAINT chk_credit CHECK (credit IN ('U', 'G')),
  9     CONSTRAINT chk_college CHECK
 10        (college IN ('Arts and Sciences',
 11                     'Education',
 12                     'Engineering',
 13                     'Business')),
 14     CONSTRAINT chk_course CHECK
 15        ( (credit = 'U' AND hrs <= 4) OR (credit = 'G' AND hrs = 3)),
 16     CONSTRAINT unq_course UNIQUE (name, college)
 17  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE STUDENT
  2  (
  3     SID          VARCHAR2 (7) CONSTRAINT pk_sid PRIMARY KEY,
  4     NAME         CHAR (14),
  5     ADDRESS      CHAR (22),
  6     BIRTHDATE    DATE,
  7     GRADELEVEL   CHAR (2) CONSTRAINT nn_glvl NOT NULL
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE SECTION
  2  (
  3     SECTION#   VARCHAR2 (8) CONSTRAINT pk_section# PRIMARY KEY,
  4     TIME       CHAR (5),
  5     MAXST      NUMBER (2),
  6     ROOM       VARCHAR2 (14),
  7     course#    CHAR (10),                                        -- added by LF
  8     empid      VARCHAR2 (8),                                     -- added by LF
  9     CONSTRAINT chk_maxst CHECK (maxst <= 35),
 10     CONSTRAINT fk_crs FOREIGN KEY (course#) REFERENCES course (course#),
 11     CONSTRAINT fk_pro FOREIGN KEY (empid) REFERENCES professor (empid)
 12  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE TAKES
  2  (
  3     GRADE      CHAR (5) CONSTRAINT nn_grade NOT NULL,
  4     section#   VARCHAR2 (8),                                     -- added by LF
  5     sid        VARCHAR2 (7),                                     -- added by LF
  6     CONSTRAINT chk_grade CHECK (grade IN ('A', 'B', 'C')),
  7     CONSTRAINT fk_sec FOREIGN KEY (section#) REFERENCES section (section#),
  8     CONSTRAINT fk_stu FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student (sid)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I took away the table abbreviations and just left the column names on the COURSE table and it worked perfectly. On the SECTION and TAKES tables, for the foreign key constraints I did the same thing and got rid of the deletion constraints but I'm getting invalid identifier errors on both tables.

Comment: And just for clarity, I'm following the format that's in the textbook for the database class I'm taking (it was written by the professor teaching it). I may have used the wrong tags to describe the language we're using so my bad on that. This is for an assignment in that class, the professor supplies the CREATE TABLE statements and we're supposed to add constraints based on an ER diagram. Here's an excerpt from the textbook: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eDdBShzgnSjISqxByJ7FKgbkLCEwXzpd

Comment: OK then; if you partially made it work, please, edit your initial message and post code you currently have. I don't know what those "invalid identifiers" are, unless I see the code.

Comment: Boy, that's going to be hard. You said: "The CREATE TABLE SECTION statement gives an invalid identifier error on line 7 pointing to course#", but - there's no course# column there. You can't create a constraint on a column that doesn't exist. The same goes for **all** foreign key constraints you created. Take a breath, think a little bit. Don't just *type letters* hoping that they'll somehow make sense, because they won't.

Comment: I'm not. I'm literally following the format that's in my textbook. If that format is wrong, so be it (in fact that's why I'm here) but I'm definitely not randomly typing letters. course# is the primary key of the COURSE table to which I'm referring in the foreign key constraint in the aforementioned format (which again could be wrong). I didn't include that code because there was no issue with it and didn't think it would affect these other CREATE TABLE statements but I'll put those up to for context as well as an example of the format my class has been told to follow.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. In CREATE TABLE SECTION you are creating the FK_CRS foreign key constraint on COURSE# column which **does not exist** in CREATE TABLE SECTION statement. That just won't work, ever.

Comment: So even though COURSE# is the primary key in COURSE, would I have to make it a column in SECTION before I add a foreign key constraint where I refer to it? Here's what my textbook has on foreign key constraints for context: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WhDsgQy2xSwjxVMqDzaGOcBh7zSokneT https://drive.google.com/open?id=12N51OCEucRn_unagqHYsqufEGK3tKJH_ Should I refer to the course# column the way the book says to but after making it a column in the table that's referencing it?

Comment: Absolutely. SECTION has to have the COURSE column. Then create a foreign key on it, pointing to COURSE table, COURSE# column.

Comment: OK then, as you almost made it work, I did some *final* modifications to your code and edited my answer which now demonstrates how it works - works OK :)